# Datatables: Selecting their items

Tags: jquery, datatables

How can I select datatables items? I have tried stuff like:

```
$("select").change(function () {
alert('changed!');
});
```

but I see no results. I also tried by name but I cannot interact with these elements. I would like to interact directly with the select and the search box.

Thank you!

Comment: do you get any javascript error? that code should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wraping it in $(document).ready function,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("select").live('change',function () {
    alert('changed!');
    });
});
```